Is it possible to get the actual key back from a hashtable
Given a hash table (or a dictionary) like:
$HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'Two' = 2; 'Three' = 3 }

(which is case insensitive by default, but doesn't has to be in every situation for my case. In fact, I have no clue of the comparer that is used in the given hashtable or dictionary)
It is easy to get the related value for a specific item:
$HashTable['two'] # Or: $HashTable.get_item('two')
2

But is it also possible to get the actual key (of a specific item) back, something like:
$HashTable.get_Key('two')

Which would return Two (which a capital T) rather than an error or two in lowercase?

Update 1
Apparently I haven't been clear in my question, so let me rephrase it:
For any given hashtable (or dictionary) with an unknown comparer, I am looking for a way to retrieve the original key of a specific item similar as I would retrieve the value of t specific item. Meaning:

If the key doesn't exist, I would not expect anything in return (similar as would look for the value using that same key)
If the key does exist, I expect a (single)  original key in return (similar as would get a single) value in return)

Meanwhile, I am starting to believe that the answer to my question is:

That is not possible

Simply because the key of an hashtable isn't reordered but only the hashcode and collision recovery data but not the whole key (/string, which might virtually unlimited in size)..
That doesn't make sense either because the whole key is still available in the .keys collection but apparently the (reverse) link with the actual item is gone...

Update 2
To be honest what I was expecting from this question, was either:

a standard way to retrieve original key
or "not possible" with possibly a why that is the case

But it turns out that I got a list of interesting alternatives which I might use instead. For my actual use case, the performance is important but more important is the fact whether the provide suggestion reacts according my expectations.
Therefore I have setup Pester test bench to confirm this:
Describe 'Retrive the original key from a hashtable or dictionary' { # https://stackoverflow.com/a/78656228

    BeforeAll {
        $CaseInsensitive = [Ordered]@{
            One   = 1
            Two   = 2
            Three = 3
            4 = 'Four'
        }

        $CaseSensitive = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]::new()
        $CaseSensitive['One']   = 1
        $CaseSensitive['two']   = 2
        $CaseSensitive['Two']   = 2
        $CaseSensitive['three'] = 3
        $CaseSensitive['Three'] = 3
        $CaseSensitive['THREE'] = 3
        $CaseSensitive[[Object]4] = 'Four'

        # mklement0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/78656228/1701026
        function GetKey($Dictionary, $lookupKey) {
            if ($Dictionary.Contains($lookupKey)) {
                $candidateKeys = $Dictionary.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq $lookupKey }, 0, 2)
                if ($candidateKeys.Count -ge 2) { $lookupKey }
                else                            { $candidateKeys[0] }
            }
        }

        # Fabrice SANGA https://stackoverflow.com/a/78656281/1701026
        # $CaseInsensitive | Add-Member -Force -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name get_Key -Value {
            # param([string] $CaseInsensitiveIndex)
            # return $this.Keys.Where{ $_ -ceq ([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($CaseInsensitiveIndex) }
        # }
        # $CaseSensitive | Add-Member -Force -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name get_Key -Value {
            # param([string] $CaseInsensitiveIndex)
            # return $this.Keys.Where{ $_ -ceq ([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($CaseInsensitiveIndex) }
        # }
        # function GetKey($Dictionary, $lookupKey) {
            # $Dictionary.get_Key($lookupKey)
        # }

        # Abraham Zinala https://stackoverflow.com/a/78657526/1701026
        # function GetKey($HashTable, $to_match) {
            # [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
            # ($entries = [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry[]]@($HashTable.GetEnumerator())),
                # [Func[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry, bool]]{
                    # param($entry)
                    # $entry.Key -match $to_match -and $entries.Where{$_.Key -match $to_match}.Count -eq 1 -or 
                    # $entry.Key -cmatch $to_match -and $entries.Where{$_.Key -match $to_match}.Count -ge 1
                # }
            # ).Key
        # }

        # iRon
        # function GetKey($Dictionary, $LookupKey) {
            # if ($Dictionary -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
                # if (-not $Dictionary.Contains($LookupKey)) { return }
            # } else {
                # if (-not $Dictionary.ContainsKey($LookupKey)) { return }
            # }
            # foreach ($Key in $Dictionary.get_Keys()) {
                # if ($Key -ceq $LookupKey) { return $Key }
                # if ($Key -ieq $LookupKey) { $iKey = $Key }
            # }
            # if ($Null -ne $iKey) { $iKey } else { $LookupKey }
        # }
    }

    Context 'Case insensitive, existing key' {


        It 'One' {
            $CaseInsensitive['One'] | Should -Be 1
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'One' | Should -BeExactly 'One'
        }

        It 'ONE' {
            $CaseInsensitive['ONE'] | Should -Be 1
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'ONE' | Should -BeExactly 'One'
        }

        It 'two' {
            $CaseInsensitive['two'] | Should -Be 2
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'two' | Should -BeExactly 'Two'
        }

        It 'Two' {
            $CaseInsensitive['Two'] | Should -Be 2
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'Two' | Should -BeExactly 'Two'
        }

        It 'TWO' {
            $CaseInsensitive['TWO'] | Should -Be 2
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'TWO' | Should -BeExactly 'Two'
        }

        It 'three' {
            $CaseInsensitive['three'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'three' | Should -BeExactly 'Three'
        }

        It 'Three' {
            $CaseInsensitive['Three'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'Three' | Should -BeExactly 'Three'
        }

        It 'THREE' {
            $CaseInsensitive['THREE'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 'THREE' | Should -BeExactly 'Three'
        }

        It '4' {
            $CaseInsensitive[[Object]4] | Should -Be 'Four'
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 4 | Should -Be 4
        }
    }

    Context 'Case insensitive, missing key' {

        It '"4"' {
            $CaseInsensitive['4'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive '4' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }
    }

    Context 'Case sensitive, existing key' {

        It 'One' {
            $CaseSensitive['One'] | Should -Be 1
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'One' | Should -BeExactly 'One'
        }

        It 'two' {
            $CaseSensitive['Two'] | Should -Be 2
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'Two' | Should -BeExactly 'Two'
        }

        It 'Two' {
            $CaseSensitive['Two'] | Should -Be 2
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'Two' | Should -BeExactly 'Two'
        }

        It 'three' {
            $CaseSensitive['three'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'three' | Should -BeExactly 'three'
        }

        It 'Three' {
            $CaseSensitive['Three'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'Three' | Should -BeExactly 'Three'
        }

        It 'THREE' {
            $CaseSensitive['THREE'] | Should -Be 3
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'THREE' | Should -BeExactly 'THREE'
        }

        It '4' {
            $CaseInsensitive[[Object]4] | Should -Be 'Four'
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive 4 | Should -Be 4
        }
    }

    Context 'Case sensitive, missing key' {

        It 'one' {
            $CaseSensitive['one'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'one' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }

        It 'ONE' {
            $CaseSensitive['ONE'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'ONE' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }

        It 'TWO' {
            $CaseSensitive['TWO'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'TWO' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }

        It 'Four' {
            $CaseSensitive['Four'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseSensitive 'Four' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }

        It '"4"' {
            $CaseInsensitive['4'] | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
            GetKey $CaseInsensitive '4' | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
        }
    }
}


Use another hashtable or the same one with inverted key value pairs?

@SantiagoSquarzon, I thought of that, but what if I don't know if the given hashtable (or dictionary) is case sensitive or not. This brings me into a catch22 with my other question (you answered): Check whether a dictionary is case sensitive

Well you already got your answer then :) you will need to do a check for each type implementing IDIctionary. For hashtable you can get it from _keycomparer field

What should happen on $HashTable.get_Key('two') if the hashtable was case-insensitive in your example? What's the use case? Are you looking to get the key belonging to a given value? I'm thinking what you want is $hashTable.GetKeyByValue(2) in which case you could use ReferenceEquals to get it.

@SantiagoSquarzon, for the first question: if the hashtable is case insensitive , I would expect Two, if the hashtable is case sensitive I would expect nothing in return as there are no matching items. For your second question, I will dig into the GetKeyByValue method but I suspect that might not work out either as the value might not be unique.

For the first answer: Isn't that what .ContainsKey is for?

If the dictionary was case insensitive there could be only 1 key with different case, if the dictionary was case sensitive then the exact casing would need to be used for .ContainsKey to return true ?

@SantiagoSquarzon, I have updated the question and hope it is somewhat clearer when I expect something (the original key) in return.

Are you after the DictionaryEntry? $HashtTable.GetEnumerator().Where{ $_.Key -match 'two' }[0]

@iRon,  I agree that isn't possible in general, and I've reworked the bottom section of my answer to discuss a hypothetically more efficient solution, based on hypothetical access to the comparer instance. That said a solution based on three non-linear lookups is possible for System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2, specifically, though in practice you may not notice the difference compared to the optimized linear lookups, except in large dictionaries.

@AbrahamZinala, no, the question is about getting the case-exact form of the original key, as used when the entry was added.

P.S., @iRon: I meant to say: it isn't possible to do efficiently in general, but it is possible, as shown in the middle section of my answer.

Thanks for adding the tests; I gather that both my and Abraham's solutions return the expected results. As for performance: I've added an alternative solution that optimizes for the case where the lookup key already is in the case-exact form; it also happens to be shorter.

@mklement0, I have updated the tests as I found a flaw in Abraham's solution (see the comment to his answer). meaning that your solution is currently to only one that really works and survives  the Pester tests.


Preface:

Small caveat: The solutions below rely on PowerShell's -eq operator to perform case-insensitive equality comparison, which implicitly occur in the context of the invariant culture, where as given hashtable / dictionary may use a different culture context, such as the current one.
While this typically won't make a difference, there are edge cases where it may.  In the absence of being able to obtain the comparer that a given hashtable / dictionary instance uses internally,[1] there's no robust solution to this problem.


I'm not aware of an efficient way to obtain the case-exact form of the original key, but the following is a concise one (at the expense of performance, 'First' can be omitted), using the intrinsic .Where() method:
@{
 'One' = 1
 'Two' = 2
 'Three' = 3
}.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq 'two' }, 'First')[0] # -> 'Two'

Note:

The above only works reliably with case-insensitive dictionaries, which PowerShell's hashtables and [ordered] hashtable literals are (note that the use of 'First'  isn't strictly necessary, but is a performance optimization: it stops looking after the first - and by definition only in a case-insensitive dictionary - match; [0] extracts the one and only element of the collection of matches that .Where() invariably returns).

With case-sensitive dictionaries, the above may report false positives - see below for a solution that handles such dictionaries too.

If, by contrast, you want to retrieve (potentially) all keys from a case-sensitive dictionary that are identical to or case variations of the given lookup key (whether or not the lookup key matches one of them case-exactly), replace
.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq 'two' }, 'First')[0] with
.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq 'two' })


The reason this is inefficient is the need to perform a linear (O(N)) search through the keys collection, and the fact that a script block must be invoked for each collection element doesn't help.



Dealing with a dictionary whose case-sensitivity is unknown requires more work, including potentially having to examine all keys:
# Note: [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] is the type
#       underlying [ordered] hashtable literals in PowerShell.
#       It - like [System.Collections.Hashtable] - is case-SENSITIVE by default; 
#       it is PowerShell that makes them case-INsensitive behind the scenes.
$dictionary = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]::new()
$dictionary['One'] = 1
$dictionary['TWO'] = 2
$dictionary['two'] = 2  # case variation
$dictionary['Three'] = 2

$lookupKey = 'two'

# -> Stores 'two' in $actualKey, the case-exact match.
$actualKey = 
  if ($dictionary.Contains($lookupKey)) {
    $candidateKeys = $dictionary.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq $lookupKey }, 0, 2)
    if ($candidateKeys.Count -ge 2) { $lookupKey }
    else                            { $candidateKeys }
  }


.Contains($lookupKey), weeds out lookup keys that do not match an existing key, whether case-insensitively or not.

.Where({ $_ -eq $lookupKey }, 0, 2) looks for at most 2 candidate (potential) key matches, case-insensitively; limiting the search to 2 candidates is a performance optimization: from the presence of two (or more) keys that are case variations of each other it can be inferred that the dictionary at hand is case-sensitive.

If there are (at least) two candidate keys ($candidateKeys.Count -ge 2), the implication is that the hashtable is case-sensitive and that the lookup key is therefore by definition already in the case-exact form (otherwise .Contains() wouldn't have returned $true), so $lookupKey is returned.

Otherwise, if only a single candidate key is returned, that key is by definition the correct one and is returned (note that there's no need to use [0] in this case in order to output the one and only element itself, because the use of an if statement causes any collection (enumerable) to be auto-enumerated, just like in the pipeline).


Alternative, which optimizes for the case where the lookup key already is in the case-exact form:
$actualKey =
  if ($dictionary.Contains($lookupKey)) {
      if (-1 -ne [Array]::IndexOf($dictionary.Keys, $lookupKey)) { $lookupKey }
      else { $dictionary.Keys.Where({ $_ -eq $lookupKey }, 'First') }
  }


Once the existence of a matching key has been confirmed via .Contains(), a case-sensitive (linear) lookup is performed first, using [Array]::IndexOf() (which performs current-culture, case-sensitive comparisons), which performs much better than a .Where() filter.

If a case-exact match is found, the lookup key is by definition already in the case-exact form.

Otherwise, the implication is that the dictionary is case-insensitive and that that is therefore sufficient to look for the first - and by definition only - key in the .Keys collection that case-insensitively  matches the lookup key, using .Where() with -eq.



An hypothetical efficient solution would require efficient (O(1)) lookups in the .Keys collection that return the matching keys themselves, but as you note, dictionaries aren't designed for that, as they translate keys into abstract hashes (numbers) for lookup of values (and these hashes have no reverse link to the keys they were derived from).
If it were possible - it isn't[1] - to obtain the System.Collections.IEqualityComparer / System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1 used by a given dictinonary instance and the specific instance used is of a type exposed via the static properties of the System.StringComparer class, such as [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase, you could at least infer case-sensitivity and optimize based on that: if the dictionary is case-sensitive and a value lookup (.Contains()) succeeds, you're by definition dealing with the case-exact form of the key; otherwise, it is sufficient to (linearly) look for the first case-insensitively matching key in .Keys.
If the given dictionary happens to be of type System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2, you could perform a binary search of the .Keys collection, taking advantage of the fact that the collection of keys is by definition sorted, along the lines of:
[Array]::BinarySearch($sortedDict.Keys, $lookupKey, [StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
With System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2, specifically, you could achieve a relatively efficient solution even without knowing the comparer, via two to three non-linear lookups (though in practice you may not notice a difference from the linear approach except in large dictionaries):

Test if the lookup key matches at all with .Contains() and stop if not.

If it does, first use the binary search case-sensitively: if it succeeds, the lookup key is by definition already in the case-exact form, so return it.

Otherwise (the dictionary must be case-insensitive), repeat the search case-insensitively, which will by definition find the one and only matching key that is a case variation of the lookup key, and return it.



[1] Neither the specific System.Collections.Hashtable ([hashtable]) type nor the dictionary interfaces (System.Collections.IDictionary and System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2) offer (public) members for accessing the comparer (and trying to use reflection to access non-public members is not only generally ill-advised, but would have to be done for each concrete dictionary-like type separately).


+1 for the alternative (and the suggestion that there is probably no way to do this). The issue with alternative is that in case the hashtable is case sensitive, I might get multiple keys in return (or just the first one). I don't think there is a way either to pull the comparer from the hashtable and use that somehow in a where filter.

@iRon. Use Add-Member and define this alternative solution as a new member of the $Hashtable object. Like this $Hashtable | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name get_Key -Value { param([string] $a) return $this.Keys.Where{ $_ -eq $a } }. If the comparer is case-sensitive, it is totally normal to possibly get multiple keys. If the comparer is case-insensitive, you only get one key.

@FabriceSANGA, "If the comparer is case-sensitive, it is totally normal to possibly get multiple keys.". I am sure whether understand what you mean by that. How I see it: (independent of the comparer), a hashtable (or dictionary) usually returns a single item (or none at all).

@iRon. If the comparer is case-sensitive, you would be able to input the keys 'Two', 'tWo', 'two' as three different keys. But calling the ScriptMethod like this get_Key('two') matches the 3 keys. That is why @mklment0 use 'First' in the where() method to retrieve only the first of them.

Thanks, @iRon. Good point re case-sensitive hashtables - I've updated the answer to show a solution for them too (and therefore also for hashtables of unknown case-sensitivity status), and I've also added a section to address the (apparently unfulfillable) desire to obtain the comparer.

Okay! I believe a solution that covers both scenarios of case-sensitive and case-insensitive matching based on count, could look something like this:
$HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'Two' = 2; 'Three' = 3 }

$to_match = 'two'

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
    ($entries = [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry[]]@($HashTable.GetEnumerator())),
    [Func[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry, bool]]{
        param($entry)
        $entry.Key -match $to_match -and $entries.Where{$_.Key -match $to_match}.Count -eq 1 -or 
        $entry.Key -cmatch $to_match -and $entries.Where{$_.Key -match $to_match}.Count -ge 1
    }
)

where we turn the hashtable  into a collection of explicit DictionaryEntry's, then filter the entries using Linq.Enumerable's Where() method.
So,

if the keys contain exactly 1 matching key, return the pair with case-insensitivity matching
but, if the keys contain more than 1 matching key, use case-sesnitive matching to return the entry.

Now, we end up with 'one' matching a single entry of 'one','One','oNe',etc, but multiple entries such as 'two','TWO', get  matched by what's being filtered for in $to_match.

+1. Sorry, for the late confirmation that this solution indeed works but I needed some time to test it (see my testing under Update 2)

At a closer look, it appears that there is actually a flaw in your approach: you assume that there are always multiple keys with the same name (but different casing) if it concerns a case sensitive dictionary, but that doesn't have to be the case. I have updated the Pester test to capture this pitfall...

@iRon, can you elaborate more on that statement? In the example posted above, it's the same $HashTable you used with no changes to it, and no other keys matching with different casing. In other words, it works for both multiple key entries, and single key entries. I may have missed something, so pardon my ignorance in advance.

$to_match = 'one' given a single entry in $HashTable matching that, it will return the original key. So, if there are multiple entries of the same key (with different casing), it matches based on exact case. So, 'one','One','onE' will return just 'one' based on $to_match.

The general constrain is that the get_Key(<key>) function should react similar to getting a value from a (case sensitive or - insensitive) hashtable. Meaning if get_Item(<key>) ($HashTable[<key>]) returns a (single) Value, get_Key(<key>) should return a (single) key and if $HashTable[<key>] returns nothing, the get_Key(<key>) function is supposed to return nothing. For your function if I create a case sensitive hashtable with a single item (just .add('One')), the get_Key('ONE') function shouldn't return anything (as $HashTable['ONE']) but your function does.

I see what you mean, I think my confusion came from your comment of Which would return Two (which a capital T) rather than an error or two in lowercase?. Unless I'm mistaken, your get_Key('one') would fail on retrieving key One, as indicated in your question. Nevertheless, I shall leave my answer here as it may be of help to others lol

Based on the Pester tests and the provided use cases
You can add a script method member get_Key to the hashtable that searches through the list of keys, the one exactly matching the title-case format (ignoring all caps*) of the specified parameter string $CaseInsensitiveKey using the System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase() method:
$Hashtable | Add-Member -Force -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name get_Key -Value {
  param([string] $CaseInsensitiveKey)
  if (($Keys = @($this.Keys.Where{ $_ -eq $CaseInsensitiveKey })).Count -gt 1) {
    return $Keys.Where{ $_ -ceq $CaseInsensitiveKey }
  }
  return $Keys[0]
}

* Title-case format includes all caps which are ignored in this case.
Basic solution
$this.Keys returns the list of keys and it is filtered by the index in the Where() method. Which means that the returned value is not fabricated. What is added from the edited solution is the additional test that the lookup key returns a value when it is indexed by the hashtable.
However, the solution is not the most optimal since the search is done twice.


Pester Test Result
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 20 tests in 19ms.
Running tests.
[+] W:\PowerShell\markdown-to-html-shortcut\MarkdownToHtmlShortcut\test.ps1 119ms (39ms|63ms)
Tests completed in 123ms
Tests Passed: 20, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0

Pester test and results

I am not look for the value, I am looking for the original (actual) key independent of the comparer used. In other words: if the key exist, I would like to retrieve its original name (which might or might not slightly differ from the search key due to the comparer used)

@iRon, I think I implemented your use case that is unaware of the Comparer implemented and it returns only one key when this one exists and is written in the title-case format.

iRon, It retrieves the key.

Ok, I will do some more testing tomorrow.

iRon ([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase('two') returns Two. Thus it looks in the list of keys the key Two and the comparison is case-sensitive.

Note that the question is unrelated to title case. The intent is to obtain the original key - as it was used on adding the entry - case-exactly, for any given dictionary of unknown case-sensitivity, which your code doesn't do. Also note that the [StringComparer] class has static properties that provide ready-made equality comparers (e.g., [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase), so there's no need to roll your own. Finally, while it doesn't hurt to show a script-method wrapper for the desired functionality, doing so isn't the focus of the question.

@mklement0. Thank you, I simplified the use case example using the [StringComparer]::InvariantCulture equality comparer. But, if you read the script method get_Key I suggest to add, you would see that the return key is filtered with the title-case lookup index. The key is not fabricated, it is the index of the search that is fabricated. The key that matches the index is returned, not the index. The index is the argument of the get_Key method.

I still don understand the title-case angle, but let me illustrate my point: Given $HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'twO' = 2; 'Three' = 3 } with your script method added,
$HashTable.get_key('two'), $HashTable.get_key('TWO') and $HashTable.get_key('twO') should  all return 'twO' - the key in the exact case it was originally defined

but your code returns nothing.


@mklement0, I understand your point, but it depends on @iRon to define the use case. What he explained suggests that the title-case key is the one that should be returned. So if  $HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'twO' = 2; 'Three' = 3 }, then $HashTable.get_key('two') does not return anything, but $HashTable.get_key('three') will return Three.

I don't think there's any ambiguity in the question ("get the actual key"), and nothing suggests that the example of the capital T  in Two was anything other than an example of a case variation. But I'll let @iRon weigh in.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@mklement0, thanks for helping to clear up the question. @Fabrice, I have added a Pester test bench under update 2, so that you can see what I expect the function to reaction (unfortunately, your suggestion fails at 6 points in the test)

@iRon, There is the solution based on the use cases. I just tweaked the previous script method and added an additional test to match the use case when the the key is missing and an additional string operation on the index key. I completed the reasoning with the proof that the returned key is original but not fabricated.

My pester tests just happens to have Title case examples, but there is constrain for that. In other words: this hash table: $HashTable = @{ 'oNe' = 1 }, is supposed to return oNe  for: $HashTable.get_Key('oNe')

Based on about_Hash_Tables and about_Arrays articles:
Update:
$HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'Two' = 2; 'Three' = 3}

$HashTable.Keys | Where-Object { $_ -eq 'two' }  # returns string of value 'Two'
$HashTable.Keys | Where-Object { $_ -eq 'foo' }  # returns $null

# or

$HashTable.Keys.Where( { $_ -eq 'two' } ) # returns Collection`1 of value @('Two')
$HashTable.Keys.Where( { $_ -eq 'foo' } ) # returns Collection`1 of value @()

Original answer:

$HashTable = @{ 'One' = 1; 'Two' = 2; 'Three' = 3; 'Single' = 1 }

$HashTable.Keys | Where-Object { $HashTable.$_ -eq 1 }

'--- or using GetEnumerator method ---'
$HashTable.GetEnumerator().Where( {$_.Value -eq 1}) |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name



I am not looking for the key based on  any value. I am looking for the orginal key based on the search in a hashtable (or dictionary) that might either be case sensitive or case insensitive.

@iRon answer updated…

Fyi, I have added some (pester) tests to the question to make the expected outcome more clear.
